# Add 1 - 5 to rows while taking into account the number of rows (may also be called tiling/binning) in Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this which is in order:

[image]

I'm not sure what the technical term is (tiling I think) but I want to add a new column that has a string of numbers ranging from 1 to 5 to it that evenly distribute as best as possible, so my dataframe looks something like this:

[image]

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 2018-11-08:**
Was asked to paste the actual data into the question.

**How my data looks currently:**

```
Name    Score
Harry   43
Sally   234
Mary    54
John    34
Francis 12
Devon   43
James   54
Holly   65
Molly   23
Nancy   12
Ben     32
```

**Here is how I want it to look:**

```
Name    Score   Tile
Harry   43  1
Sally   234 1
Mary    54  1
John    34  2
Francis 12  2
Devon   43  3
James   54  3
Holly   65  4
Molly   23  4
Nancy   12  5
Ben 32  5
```

**EDIT FURTHER QUESTION 2018-11-08:**

[image]

```
Name    Animals Tile
Mary    cat 1
John    cat 2
Molly   cat 3
Harry   dog 1
Sally   dog 2
Francis dog 3
James   dog 1
Devon   horse   1
Nancy   mouse   1
Ben mouse   2
Holly   snake   1


import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Harry','Sally','Mary','John','Francis','Devon','James','Holly','Molly','Nancy','Ben'], 'Score': [43,234,54,34,12,43,54,65,23,12,32],
                 'Animal': ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'dog', 'snake', 'dog', 'mouse', 'horse']})
tiles = pd.qcut(df.index, 3, labels=False)
tiles=tiles+1
df['tiles']=tiles
print(df)
```

**FURTHER EDITTED FURTHER QUESTION 2018-11-08:**

I changed my code like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Harry','Sally','Mary','John','Francis','Devon','James','Holly','Molly','Nancy','Ben'], 'Score': [43,234,54,34,12,43,54,65,23,12,32],
                 'Animal': ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'dog', 'snake', 'dog', 'mouse', 'horse']})
tiles = pd.qcut(np.arange(len(df["Animal"])),3)
df['tiles']=tiles
print (df)
```

And I got the following result:

[image]

Comment: Are they in order, or do you want them to be randomly sampled?

Comment: Ummmm why 1 repeat 3 times ? Also , can you post your sample data here (Not picture )

Comment: @ALollz they are in order

Comment: @W-B I'm not sure how else it would distribute if the amount of rows you have doesn't match your range. I shall paste the data in now...

Comment: It's just a matter of whether 1 should be repeated 3 times, or 5 (or any other number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pd.qcut on the index on your dataframe (assuming you have an integer index):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Harry','Sally','Mary','John','Francis','Devon','James','Holly','Molly','Nancy','Ben'], 'Score': [43,234,54,34,12,43,54,65,23,12,32]})
tiles = pd.qcut(df.index, 5, labels=False)
tiles=tiles+1
df['tiles']=tiles
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Really helpful! Was wondering though, how would you do it if your index wasn't an integer and you had a factor of 3? I've put my example in the original question under "EDIT FURTHER QUESTION 2018-11-08:" as well as my code

Comment: @semiflex as W.B. wrote below, you can replace df.index with np.arange(len(df)) ; in this way you don't need to have an integer index.

Comment: So in my case, I have to add: np.arange(len(df["Animal"]))

Comment: So I tried as yourself and W.B. suggested and I got a slightly different result. I've attached it to my original question under: FURTHER EDITTED FURTHER QUESTION 2018-11-08:

Comment: you have to use this: tiles = pd.qcut(np.arange(len(df["Animal"])),3,labels=False)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you need `qcut`

```
pd.qcut(np.arange(len(df)),5,labels=[1,2,3,4,5])
Out[175]: 
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ..., 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need `modulus` to split the length of the dataframe.

See mockup below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from first import *
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Harry', 'Sally','Mary', 'James', 'Ben', 'Nancy', 'Francis'],
 'Score': [10, 15, 18, 20, 25, 30,35]},)
df['Tile'] = range(len(df))
df['Tile'] = df['Tile']%5+1

df
```

see results:

[image]